# How to fix FastCGI timeout issues in Plesk?

Tags: php, centos, fastcgi, plesk, connection-timeout

PHP support is currently set to: run as Fast CGI.

I keep getting these errors in my server log:

> mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds
>
> Premature end of script headers: index.php

Should be quick fix I think, but I cant find the file to edit. Is this something I can change from Plesk.

Anyone know how to increase the timeout?

Comment: You can check this answer:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488567/premature-end-of-script-headers-index-php-mod-fcgid-read-data-timeout-in-61-s/15931470#15931470

Answer (score 7):

In Plesk 12.x and similar go to *Web Server Settings* and set the following directives:

*Additional directives for HTTP & HTTPS*

```
FcgidBusyTimeout 300
FcgidIOTimeout 250
```

Above lines will change the timeout for scripts that are quiet too long and take too long to execute.

*Additional nginx directives*

```
proxy_read_timeout 300;
```

Above lines will change the proxy timeout.

If the problem persist, increase the values.

See also: [Premature end of script headers: index.php, mod_fcgid: read data timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14488567/55075)

---

Check the screenshots for the guidance:

[image: Plesk 12.x - Web Server Settings - Additional Apache directives: Additional directives for HTTP & HTTPS - FcgidBusyTimeout & FcgidIOTimeout]

[image: Plesk 12.x - Web Server Settings - Additional nginx directives - proxy_read_timeout]

Answer (score 5):

A solution provided in the forum of Plesk by Parallels staff

> Edit the file:
>
> /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf
>
> Specifically, change
>
> FcgidIOTimeout 45
>
> to
>
> FcgidIOTimeout 3600
>
> 3600 seconds = 1 hour. Should be long enough for most but adjust
>   upwards if required. I saw one example quoting 7200 seconds in there.
>
> Finally, restart Apache to make the new setting active.
>
> apachectl graceful

Hope it helps

R

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, he doesn't want to raise timeout but prevent FCGI from timing out.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this was to change the PHP settings in the plesk control pannel as per the screenshot.[PHP Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0EPE.png)

Comment: Why don't you provide solution here, in answer? It'd be much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of Plesk the fcgid.conf file has moved to:

> /etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf

I had some issues importing an xml file into wordpress. It kept on giving a 500 Internal Error. The error log showed:

> [Wed Jul 26 13:18:00.219226 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 4751] [client
>   145.97.205.8:60155] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds
>
> [Wed Jul 26 13:18:00.219505 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 4751]
>   (110)Connection timed out: [client 145.97.205.8:60155] mod_fcgid:
>   ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function

After following some advice - as the PHP.INI settings made no difference - i changed some settings as advised:

Original:

```
FcgidIOTimeout 45
```

To:

```
FcgidIOTimeout 3600
```

Also added:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 500
<IfModule !mod_fastcgi.c>
```

Worked like a charm. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After changing max_execution_time = 3600 in /etc/php.ini solved my problem.