# PHP server is timing out when it should be reporting errors

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm learning php/laravel so I don't completely know my way around yet. I've encountered this strange behaviour and I don't know how to solve it.

When I run my php server with `php artisan serve` or `valet start` and visit the page on my localhost, if my code has no errors then the page is loaded as expected.

However, if I purposely remove some important things like `}` or `;`, and reload the page, rather than reporting an error, the page just keeps trying to load for what feels like minutes before timing out with a `504`.

Even if I correct the error and refresh the page, it will continue timing out with `504`.

I've discovered that if put the error back in and I run `brew services restart mysql`, the page loads and reports the error to me as expected. But if I make a different error, the page `504` again.

If I run `brew services stop mysql`, then error reporting always works as expected and I don't get `504`. But I want to have `mysql` for learning php/laravel!

Hope that makes sense, really appreciate any help!

Comment: try directly with localhost/yourapp if you are using apache. if it work well then no error in code.

Comment: Does this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40239537/504-gateway-timeout-error-while-selecting-300-000-rows-from-mysql-database

Comment: @DevsiOdedra there are definitely errors, I'm purposely adding them in

Comment: @skndrkhtr5 my DB has very small amount of data, <10 rows

Comment: go to storage/laravel/logs/laravel.txt for more info

Comment: check if you have turned off your debug in your env

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this, I don't know the exact problem but it was happening because my laravel app was not connecting to MYSQL database. I downgraded MYSQL from version 8 to 5.7 and it works fine now.