# NodeJS - timeout on large file download

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to download a fairly large file (500MB) from an NodeJS API endpoint, but the following code appears times out with a 504 Gateway Timeout:

```
  async download(res: Response) {
    const path = `${this.EXCEL_SAVE_DIR}/report.xlsx`;
    try {
      if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
        res.download(path);
      } else {
        logger.debug(`download -> file not found at: ${path} `);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      logger.debug(`download -> error: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
    }
  }
```

Is it possible to avoid these timeouts?

Comment: are you using any reverse proxy servers? nginx ?

Comment: I'm hosting on Elastic beanstalk if that helps?

Comment: is there any services of apache or nginx running ? have you checked from where 504 is returning? is it before hitting node server?

Comment: I've got nginx service running on there. The 504 returns when I hit the download api endpoint which calls the above code to download the 500MB file.

Comment: SO error must be from nginx you can configure the max time limit in nginx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002268/prevent-nginx-504-gateway-timeout-using-php-set-time-limit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453388/nginx-reverse-proxy-causing-504-gateway-timeout

Comment: It is due to the max time limit settings in nginx, change it in config

Answer (score 2):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout

Increase proxy time out in Nginx

`proxy_read_timeout 600s;`