# Icon with identifier "default-not-found" is not registered

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I am getting every now and than the following error:

> 1437425804: Icon with identifier "default-not-found" is not registered

This error occurs only, if a backend users is logged in. For users, who are just visiting the website (without a backend user login session) the website works just fine.

I am not aware of an icon with the identifier `default-not-found` and don't know where to start debugging. Extension scanner looks fine. Anyone a hint?

---

EDIT

This is the backtrace for the error:

> Fri, 19 Mar 2021 12:28:52 +0100 [CRITICAL] request="915b1165ead20" component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.DebugExceptionHandler": Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1437425804: Icon with identifier "default-not-found" is not registered" | TYPO3\CMS\Core\Exception thrown in file /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Imaging/IconRegistry.php in line 674. Requested URL: https://www.example.com/typo3/index.php?route=%2Fmain&token=--AnonymizedToken-- - {"TYPO3_MODE":"BE","exception":"TYPO3\CMS\Core\Exception: Icon with identifier "default-not-found" is not registered" in /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Imaging/IconRegistry.php:674
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Imaging/IconFactory.php(101): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry->getIconConfigurationByIdentifier('default-not-fou...')
>
> #1 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/ViewHelpers/IconViewHelper.php(95): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconFactory->getIcon('default-not-fou...', 'small', NULL, Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Type\Icon\IconState))
>
> #2 /.../htdocs/public/typo3temp/var/cache/code/fluid_template/Standard_action_item_b54b300f03583ab82882169cfd221356f096f500.php(77): TYPO3\CMS\Core\ViewHelpers\IconViewHelper::renderStatic(Array, Object(Closure), Object(TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContext))
>
> #3 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/View/AbstractTemplateView.php(186): Standard_action_item_b54b300f03583ab82882169cfd221356f096f500->render(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContext))
>
> #4 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Backend/ToolbarItems/ShortcutToolbarItem.php(75): TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\View\AbstractTemplateView->render()
>
> #5 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Controller/BackendController.php(329): TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Backend\ToolbarItems\ShortcutToolbarItem->getItem()
>
> #6 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Controller/BackendController.php(276): TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Controller\BackendController->renderToolbar()
>
> #7 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Controller/BackendController.php(214): TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Controller\BackendController->renderTopbar()
>
> #8 [internal function]: TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Controller\BackendController->mainAction(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest))#9 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Http/RouteDispatcher.php(66): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>
> #10 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Http/RequestHandler.php(94): TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Http\RouteDispatcher->dispatch(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest))
>
> #11 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Middleware/SignalSlotDeprecator.php(49): TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Http\RequestHandler->handle(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest))
>
> #12 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(172): TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Middleware\SignalSlotDeprecator->process(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest), Object(TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Http\RequestHandler))
>
> #13 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Middleware/SiteResolver.php(69): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest))
>
> #14 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(172): TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Middleware\SiteResolver->process(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))
>
> #15 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Middleware/AdditionalResponseHeaders.php(41): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest))
>
> #16 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(172): TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Middleware\AdditionalResponseHeaders->process(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))
>
> #17 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Middleware/OutputCompression.php(47): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest))
>
> #18 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(172): TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Middleware\OutputCompression->process(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))
>
> #19 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Middleware/BackendUserAuthenticator.php(78): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest))
>
> #20 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(172): TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Middleware\BackendUserAuthenticator->process(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))
>
> #21 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Middleware/BackendRouteInitialization.php(58): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest))
>
> #22 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(172): TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Middleware\BackendRouteInitialization->process(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))
>
> #23 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Middleware/ForcedHttpsBackendRedirector.php(55): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest))
>
> #24 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(172): TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Middleware\ForcedHttpsBackendRedirector->process(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))
>
> #25 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Middleware/LockedBackendGuard.php(75): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest))
>
> #26 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(172): TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Middleware\LockedBackendGuard->process(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))
>
> #27 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Middleware/NormalizedParamsAttribute.php(45): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest))
>
> #28 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(172): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Middleware\ormalizedParamsAttribute->process(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))
>
> #29 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(78): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest))
>
> #30 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/AbstractApplication.php(85): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest))
>
> #31 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Http/Application.php(72): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\AbstractApplication->handle(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest))
>
> #32 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/AbstractApplication.php(97): TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Http\Application->handle(Object(TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequest))
>
> #33 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/index.php(25): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\AbstractApplication->run()
>
> #34 /.../htdocs/typo3_src-10.4.12/typo3/index.php(26): {closure}()
>
> #35 {main}"}

Comment: Maybe, you have the AdminPanel active? Not really sure, if it's using icons (especially missing icons), but may it's extended by an extension... Just some thoughts for debugging...

Comment: @JulianHofmann No, `ext:adminpanel` is not active :-(

Comment: Try to get a backtrace for that error from the log file. Then you'll know exactly where something tries to show an icon for a non-registered icon type.

Comment: @JonasEberle I have added the backtrace but I can't see, where it goes wrong. Do you have any hint?

Comment: I see TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Backend\ToolbarItems\ShortcutToolbarItem->getItem() as the origin. That is indeed a core function and I have no idea why the icon is not registered. Maybe it'll get fixed by updating to the latest v10.4?

Comment: At position #28 a "N" for "NormalizedParamsAttribute" is missing. Is this a copy&paste error?

Comment: I don't get position #1 where getIcon('default-not-fou...', ...) was called with parameter "default-not-found." This iconIdentifier will only be used as fallback WITHIN getIcon() if an iconIdentifier was not found. Template "Standard_action_item" is a reference to Item.html where <core:icon identifier="apps-toolbar-menu-shortcut" ... /> was used. If you see this error again, please search fluid-template cache directory for default-not-found and post a few lines before/after here again.

Comment: Please check if bookmarks are activated for your users: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/UserTsconfig/Options.html?highlight=enablebookmarks#enablebookmarks. If value is 0 please test with 1. If it solves the problem, it is a bug which should be reported to TYPO3

Answer (score 0):

This is not a TYPO3 problem. Because of limited RAM the backend_icon.json file can not be loaded in IconRegistry (file_get_contents). So the json ist false or empty. That will be confirmed by a PHP Warning `argument in foreach as not an array` in TYPO3 sys_log and PHP error log.

Maybe there are too many apache requests on your server or too many opened FastCGI processes or another process consuming too much RAM.

Please have a look into your RAM usage or contact your hoster to have a look.

Not tested, but maybe you or your hoster can fix that with:

```
FcgidBusyTimeout 300
FcgidIOTimeout 250
```

Link: [How to fix FastCGI timeout issues in Plesk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905004/how-to-fix-fastcgi-timeout-issues-in-plesk)

Comment: Thanks for your info! We have tried this, but unfortunately it does not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi @chris IMO your hoster has updated your package to a higher version which allows a lot more concurrent requests and RAM usage. Can you confirm that this issue is solved now?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today when I updated TYPO3 from 10.4.9 to 10.4.20.
After deleting the folder ./var/cache, the message disappeared.

Comment: First of all: welcome to stackoverflow! Thanks for your info, that is exactly, what I am doing to make it temporary work again: clearing all cache. I am very curious, if this error happens again to you and if so, how do you solve it.

Comment: In my case after that the error didn't appear anymore